# Apache writable directory security

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

I am running Apache with the user apache

My webroot is /var/www/html

the file owner of /var/www/html is myUser:myUser with permissions 744

I have a PHP script for file uploads that should write files to /var/www/html/files

If I make the owner of the files directory myUser:apache and set the permissions to 774, would that be a secure setup? Will I find myself hacked or have GB of unsavoury pictures uploaded to my site?

I am also considering a /var/www/html/files/.htaccess to be

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$" Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Is the server shared?  If so another site may be able to also write to that folder if the web server has the privilege.  The FilesMatch is a good idea in that case.

Comment: Will the public be able to upload files?

Comment: The reason the directory is writable is to allow staff to upload images via a password protected CMS-like interface. The public is not able to upload files.